# How to deal with failure in the middle of giving a HTTP response?

Tags: http

I've recently stumbled upon multiple talks claiming that you should start responding to any incoming HTTP request ASAP, which seems reasonable, but I'm not clear on how to communicate  failure when employing this strategy.

Let's image the situation where we send a response code of 200 and start rendering a HTML page. As we construct the body, the data flows in from various db queries and suddenly an error occurs. It's a bit too late to change our mind at this point in time.

Or maybe a more practical example:

We're providing an API that potentially delivers a *lot* of data. To keep it fast, we stream the data off the DB connection through some project function and then into a streaming JSON encoder that writes right to the socket. And poof, something goes wrong. DB connection breaks up, reconnection attempts time out. We've just flushed 100K JSON objects, but the result set was actually bigger than that.

Is there any good way to die gracefully half way into an HTTP response?

In the HTML case, one could always print some human readable information. And in the API, once can respond with `{ "results": [ /* payload goes here */ ], "error": { /* error information */ } }`, which is ok, since the error is written after the payload. But ideally I would like to use something built into the HTTP protocol. It seems weird to say 200 and then deliver an error. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you provide links for the talks you mention, if you have them?

Answer (score 1):

Once the status code is sent the only option you have is closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good way to die gracefully half way into an HTTP
>   response?

No, if you flushed http status to client - there is no possibility to change it, so the only approach is to generate output fully on server and then start streaming it to client with proper http code

NOTE - checkout gzip compression for big JSON data